# Why is Object.Equals preferred to calling String.Equals from an instance?

Tags: c#, string, equality

I am preparing for certification on C# and face the following question (code edited for simplicity):

```
class Class
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "hello";
}

...

Class a = new Class();
Class b = new Class();
Class c = a;

Assert.IsTrue(a.Name == b.Name);
Assert.IsTrue(a.Name.Equals(b.Name));
Assert.IsTrue(Object.Equals(a.Name, b.Name));

Assert.IsTrue(a.Name == c.Name);
Assert.IsTrue(a.Name.Equals(c.Name));
Assert.IsTrue(Object.Equals(a.Name, c.Name));

Assert.IsTrue(a.Name == a.Name);
Assert.IsTrue(a.Name.Equals(a.Name));
Assert.IsTrue(Object.Equals(a.Name, a.Name));
```

All these assert passed.

Dumps of certification tests say that `Object.Equals(*.Name, *.Name)` is the right answer and `*.Name.Equals(*.Name)` is wrong.

Why?

Comment: Could it be due to `NullReferenceException` being more likely thrown in the second case? You could have your `*` objects throwing it in both cases, but if `Name` property of the first object is `null`, then the first way you do this will return false, while the second one will throw the exception.

Comment: Maybe it's to be safe in the case `Name` is null, although `==` should take care of that (only in the particular case of strings, or any other type where `==` falls back to `Equals` for non null operands).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `x.Name.Equals(y.Name)` will throw `NullReferenceException` if `x.Name` is `null` while `Object.Equals(x.Name, y.Name)` will perform a valid comparison

Comment: You right! There is phrase "method must not throw an exception" in the question.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.Equals` first compares object references, then it calls `String.Equals` for further equality check.

`String.Equals` tests strings for equality. It is invoked with the method name Equals or with the equality operator.

`Object.Equals` compares the contents of objects. It first checks whether the references are equal, as does `object.ReferenceEquals`. But then it calls into derived Equals methods to test equality further.

Read more explanation about [Object.Equals](http://www.dotnetperls.com/object-equals) and [String.Equals](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-equals)